# Django ORM filter logic for foreign key is giving unclear results

Tags: django, django-models

I have following two query set as properties of django model

```
    1 - Comment.objects.filter(ForeignKeyField=self) 
    2 - Comment.objects.filter(ForeginKeyField=self.id)
```

I am not why both these lines are giving same result , namely CommentObjectList ? Why I am able to filter the Comment Resultset with self and self.id both ??

Answer (score 0):

The FK field actually holds the primary key for the related record. So

```
Comment.objects.filter(ForeginKeyField=self.id)
```

should give you the result you want (assuming `self` here is an instance of the foreign key model)

```
Comment.objects.filter(ForeginKeyField=self)
```

would try and stuff the entire instance in and match that, so you'd be matching an `int` or `UUID` (depending on what kind of key you have)  with an instance of the FK object, and of course this will not match.

Side note: field names should use underscores in Django, by convention, so `foreign_key_field`, not `ForeignKeyField`.